# JavaFX setOnScroll being called twice on long mouse wheel scroll

Tags: javafx-2

I have set up an AnchorPane to handle a scroll event using the following code in the initialize() method of the AnchorPane

```
    this.setOnScroll(event -> {
        logger.info("scroll action detected");
        event.consume();
    });
```

It works fine, however if the scroll on the mouse wheel is more than say two ticks the event is triggered twice, any reason why?  Workaround?

Answer (score 0):

found the issue, had a thread holding up the other events from being displayed, turns out an event is fired per tick of the mouse wheel they just were not showing up immediately.  I should be able to use this to do something with the first event and ignore the immediate others